# SharedInstance in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

Can anybody help me to convert this code into Swift?

Here I mention `.h` and `.m` in Objective-C code.

`Abc` is a `UIViewController`. I want to perform this method in my Swift code. S how is possible?

`Abc.h`

```
+ (Abc*)sharedInstance;
- (void) startInView:(UIView *)view;
- (void) stop;
```

`Abc.m`

```
static Abc*sharedInstance;

+ (Abc*)sharedInstance
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (!sharedInstance)
        {
            sharedInstance = [[Abc alloc] init];
        }

        return sharedInstance;
    }
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: You have to show us what you tried, and let us know what issues did you run into.

Comment: You still need to learn Swift, if you plan to develop in it.

Comment: Why is this question marked as too broad and put on hold? Its a simple question of how to create a Singleton in Swift.

Answer (score 6):

In swift the best and cleanest way is simply this

```
static let sharedInstance = ABC()
```

No need for `structs` or `class variable`, which are still a valid way of doing it but its not very Swift like.

Not sure you would want to use a Singleton for `UIViewControllers` but in general a Singleton class in Swift would look like this

```
class ABC {

     static let sharedInstance = ABC()

     var testProperty = 0

     func testFunc() {

     }
}
```

and than in your other classes you would just say

```
let abc = ABC.sharedInstance

abc.testProperty = 5
abc.testFunc()
```

or call it directly

```
ABC.sharedInstance.testProperty = 5
ABC.sharedInstance.testFunc()
```

Also as a side note if you use a Singleton class and you have an initialiser you should make it private

```
class ABC {

     static let sharedInstance = ABC()

     private init() {

    }
}
```